# How to enable Chatter Communities?

Tags: community

I want to use chatter with customer portal. I searched on google and found that this can be done using Chatter Communities. Any idea how to enable chatter communities?

Answer (score 4):

Since Chatter communities are outdated, and maybe someone might stumble upon this post for how to enable chatter in communities (since this is one of the top google results for this question). In lightnign communities, chatter is integrated out of the box, However, for guest users, there is a setting that enables them to use chatter,  under community administration in the preferences tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think its in Pilot. You need to submit a request

You can find the link for the request in the [FAQ](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/communities/faq/).
Third Question from the bottom

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question to salesforce this week.  Communities is coming out after ALL the instances are done upgrading to summer13, sometimes around the middle of June.

Release notes make it sound like it's available when the release happens, but it's not.